# How to apply a vue.js filter by it's 'name'

Tags: filter, vue.js

How may we call/apply a *vue.js filter* by it's 'name'?

For example: `col.format == 'date_format'`, where `date_format` is a vue.js 
filter

The cols are defined like so:

```
cols = [
  {field: 'dt_joined', format: 'date_format'},
  {field: 'dt_trained', format: 'date_format'},
  {field: 'salary', format: 'money_format'}
]

// register filters
Vue.filter('date_format', function (x) {
  return x === null ? null : new Date(x).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
})

td(v-else-if='col.format') {{ props.item[col.field] | col.format }}
td(v-else) {{ props.item[col.field] }}

//- td {{ props.item.dt_joined | date_format }}
//- td {{ props.item.salary | money_format }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you would need to set `col.format` to be the actual function, not the name of the function:

```
let date_format = Vue.filter('date_format');
let money_format = Vue.filter('money_format');

let cols = [
  { field: 'dt_joined', format: date_format },
  { field: 'dt_trained', format: date_format },
  { field: 'salary', format: money_format }
]
```

Then `foo | col.format` will apply the function being pointed at by `col.format` to the `foo` variable before rendering it.

Comment: ah I get that now. Thanks

Comment: This even suggests that we *don't do it* ... oh well https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4405#event-885979226